# HashSet Contains method, unexpected behavior

Tags: c#, hashset

I hava a type `Relation` that overrides `GetHashCode` and `Equals`.

```
    /// <see cref="System.Object.Equals"/>
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        bool equals = false;
        if (obj is Relation)
        {
            Relation relation = (Relation)obj;
            equals = name.Equals(relation.name);
        }
        return equals;
    }

    /// <see cref="System.Object.GetHashCode"/>
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return name.GetHashCode();
    }
```

I have two `Relation` objects `relation1` and `relation2`.

I have a `HashSet<Relation>` named `relations`.

```
HashSet<Relation> relations = new HashSet<Relation>();
relations.Add(relation1);
```

The following snippet is supposed to output the hash code of `relation1` and `relation2`.

```
HashSet<Relation>.Enumerator enumerator = relations.GetEnumerator();
enumerator.MoveNext();
Console.WriteLine(relations.Comparer.GetHashCode(enumerator.Current));
Console.WriteLine(relations.Comparer.GetHashCode(relation2));
```

The output is:

```
134042217
134042217
```

The following snippet compares `relation1` and `relation2` for equality.

```
Console.WriteLine(relations.Comparer.Equals(enumerator.Current, relation2));
```

The output is:

```
True
```

However, when I try to determine if the hashSet contains `relation2` I get an unexpected result.

```
relations.Contains(relation2)
```

The output is:

```
False
```

I would expect `True`.

Here is what I understood from MSDN: in order to determine the presence of an element, `Contains` is supposed to call `GetHashCode` first and `Equals` then. If both methods return `True` then there is a matching.

Can you give me an explanation ?

Comment: show us how did you implement `Equals` and `GetHashCode`.

Comment: Is your class mutable in hashed fields?

Comment: It would be much easier to help you if you could provide a short but complete program demonstrating the problem.

Comment: How do you know that your enumerator's current position is indeed pointing to `relation1`? Did you check? `HashSet` is an unordered container.

Comment: @Numid: you haven't shown `relation2`, have you?

Comment: @MatthewWalton Good point. However, I only added `relation1` into the hashSet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would happen if you changed `Name` after inserting the first object into the HashSet.

The HashSet recorded the object's original hashcode, which is not the same as the second object.

Comment: Indeed `Name` was updated right after the insertion into the hashSet.

Comment: @Numid: See Eric Lippert's [Guidelines and rules for GetHashCode](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/28/guidelines-and-rules-for-gethashcode.aspx).  The rule you're violating is, "Rule: the integer returned by GetHashCode must never change while the object is contained in a data structure that depends on the hash code remaining stable."

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a test program with your overrides in it.

```
internal class Relation
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        bool equals = false;
        if (obj is Relation)
        {
            Relation relation = (Relation)obj;
            equals = Name.Equals(relation.Name);
        }
        return equals;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Name.GetHashCode();
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var relation1 = new Relation() {Name = "Bob"};
        var relation2 = new Relation {Name = "Bob"};
        var relations = new HashSet<Relation>();
        relations.Add(relation1);
        var does = relations.Contains(relation2);
        // does is now true
    }
}
```

So in the minimal case, your code does what you expect. Therefore I suggest that something else is going on that's causing `relation1` and `relation2` to not be the same by the time you do the `Contains` check.

Comment: Thank you. I definitely need to go deeper and analyse my complete work flow.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your snippets I wrote the following full sample:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var r1 = new Relation("name");
        var r2 = new Relation("name");

        HashSet<Relation> r = new HashSet<Relation>();
        r.Add(r1);

        bool test = r.Contains(r2);
    }
}

class Relation
{
    public readonly string Name;

    public Relation(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        bool equals = false;
        if (obj is Relation)
        {
            Relation relation = (Relation)obj;
            equals = Name.Equals(relation.Name);
        }
        return equals;
    }

    /// <see cref="System.Object.GetHashCode"/>
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Name.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

The value of 'test' is true. The only way I can explain the difference in behaviour between your code and this sample is that the Name property must not be the same between the two objects at the time that you perform the Contains check.